# Localization in c++

Tags: c++, xml

I am using rc files to localize my application which works fine.

Unfortunately there are is one module which uses an xml file to match the label name. The functionality of this XML file is much more than just some labels on the form but its irrelevant for this question.

The code reads the xml and constructs a form for data entry. What is the best way to localize this xml? I want to avoid having multiple versions of this file. The part of the xml looks as under

```
<Attribute name="Description" displayname="Summary" desc="Short Description"     type="TEXT" length="32" edit="1" column="DESCRIP"/>
```

The displayname from above is the label on my form.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't want to have multiple XML files, you need to have some kind of "lookup-mechanism". Then you could provide localized texts in rc files and use an ID within your XML (e.g. `name`) to get the localized text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, there are 2 ways to localize the XML :

- at file level : one xml file per language
- at string level : you put labels in the (unique) xml files and lookup localized strings for those labels in your rc files.